# TestCafe BrowserStack

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browserstack

I use the TestCafe module "testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack". It works well with the Browser and the OS. But how to use the module with iOS devices? I tried

```
browserstack:Safari:iPad Pro 12.9 2018
```

But the message is that the browser was not found. 
The common usage for desktop is

```
browserstack:Safari:OS X Sierra
```

Anyone can help me how to use it with iOS and Devices?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of all browsers available for testing by using `testcafe -b browserstack`.
For example, I have these ones:

- "browserstack:iPad@3.2"
- "browserstack:iPad 2@4.3.2"
- "browserstack:iPad 2 (5.0)@5.0"

Thus, you can choose any available browser from the list.
I didn't find the `browserstack:Safari:iPad Pro 12.9 2018` option in the list, but I found "browserstack:iPad Pro 12.9 2018@12.1".

Probably, you do not need to clarify that you want to use the Safari browser.

Comment: The problem is, I can choose on Browserstack to use Chrome or Safari on this iPad configuration. The URL to the Test-drive is: https://live.browserstack.com/dashboard#os=iOS&os_version=11&device=iPad+Pro+12.9&device_browser=chrome
The 12.1 you use is the latest Safari on Mojave not on iOS, so Sam confused about your configuration.

Comment: Choosing of a browser is now available in Live mode but not for Automation (see [FAQ](https://www.browserstack.com/question/659)).